# Xcode Geocoding - current address

Tags: xcode, mkmapview, geocoding

Hy , 
Im new in the xcode world so , some help would be usefull .i created an project with a map .as the map is showing my current location , how can i set so that when i click on the blue circle , instede of "current location" shows my current address ? Some tutorials would be helpfull ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has some decent documentation that will help get you started and along on the right path.

Take a look at the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW1) and also the reference guide for the [CLGeocoder class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder).

Here's also [a blog by Jonathan Field](http://jonathanfield.me/jons-blog/clgeocoder-example.html) you can refer to.